# Obter local e tamanho do console em pixels

Tags: .net, vb.net, console

Tem alguma forma de obter o tamanho e localização do `System.Console` em **pixels** e não em caracteres? Já tentei assim:

```
'Para o tamanho:
Dim X, Y As Integer
X = Console.WindowWidth * 8
Y = Console.WindowHeigth * 12
Dim final As Size = New Size(X, Y)
```

Mas eu penso, e se o usuário mudou a fonte do console? Grato desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a [função `GetCurrentConsoleFont`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683176(v=vs.85).aspx), será retornado informações como o índice numérico da fonte na *tabela de fontes de console* e a [estrutura `COORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682119(v=vs.85).aspx), que conterá as informações de *largura* e *altura*.

1. Declare o *namespace*:

   ```
   Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
   ```
2. Declare as estruturas:

   ```pascal
   Public Structure Coord
       Dim X As Short
       Dim Y As Short
   End Structure

   Public Structure _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO
       Dim nFont As Integer
       Dim dwFontSize As Coord
   End Structure
   ```
3. Declare as funções:

   ```
   <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
   Public Function GetStdHandle(ByVal nStdHandle As Integer) As Integer
   End Function

   <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
   Public Function GetCurrentConsoleFont(ByVal hConsoleOutput As Integer,
                                         ByVal bMaximumWindow As Boolean,
                                         ByRef lpConsoleCurrentFont As _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO) As Boolean
   End Function
   ```
4. Declare a constante:

   ```
   Private Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE As Integer = -11&
   ```
5. Na função principal, faça:

   ```pascal
   Sub Main()
       Dim CurrentFont As _CONSOLE_FONT_INFO
       Dim Coordenadas As Coord
       Dim hConsoleOut As Integer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

       Dim ObterFonte As Boolean = GetCurrentConsoleFont(hConsoleOut, False, CurrentFont)
       If (ObterFonte) Then
           Coordenadas = CurrentFont.dwFontSize
           Console.WriteLine("X: {0} / Y: {1}", Coordenadas.X, Coordenadas.Y)
       Else
           Console.WriteLine("Não foi possível obter as informações sobre a fonte deste Console.")
       End If

       Console.ReadKey()
   End Sub
   ```

Para obter uma gama maior de informações, use a [função `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683177(v=vs.85).aspx).